# Need to apply automatically an XSLT to an XML in Microsoft Word

Tags: xml, ms-word

I've got an XML file which is linked to an XSLT file.
The output of the xslt is formal HTML.

Actually, when i'm opening the XML with Word, a "pop-up" ask me which xsl i want to apply, but by default we see the xml data. Once i've selected my xsl, the html page is rendered.

My question is a quite simple one, how can i apply automatically the xsl ?

Comment: This is *not* an XSLT question -- retagged.

Comment: Stylesheets (CSS or XSLT) are not mandatory for the XML consumer (MS Word, in this case)

Comment: I know, but i'm interested into the output of the XML+XSLT. I mean, my aim is to avoid the use of "xsltproc" in order to use the raw xml into Word, and make it watchable using xslt.